# Как использовать promise в c++ для синхронизации функций?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Я новичок в многопоточном программировании. Не совсем поима зачем вообще нужны promise в С++ю Посмотрела примеры их использования, и на сколько я поняла, они нужный для того чтобы получить future. В примерах с promise, которые я нашла, все время создается какая-то функция (которая передается треду на исполнение), которая принимает promise и потом внутри делает set_value и после этого соответсвующий этому promise future, делает get. Но совсем непонятно вообще зачем это на практике, Хотелось бы  чтобы у меня можно было синхронизировать работу всех тредов с помощью этого promise. Допустим у меня есть массив функций и массив тредов, и я хочу чтобы эти треды выполняли эти функции но так, чтобы пока один выполняет другие его не ждали, а с помощью промиса могли работать в фоновом режиме. Можно л это как-то реализовать, Я просто совсем запуталась(

Comment: в смысле промисы не нужно использовать?

Comment: Не надо использовать промисы для решения Вашей конкретной задачи (работы со многими потоками разом). Это примитив синхронизации достаточно низкого уровня (деталь для реализации std::async). Какой примитв вам нужен на самом деле - непонятно, поскольку детали задачи не описаны,